# [Laravel]calc table column specfic range question

Tags: laravel

[UPDATE]
I'm studying number sum at laravel.
I would like to calculate table's columns total amount every month.

I wrote below code and I got this dd result (image)

```
 public function count()
    {

    Contact::whereYear('created_at', 2021)
    ->orderBy('created_at')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function ($row) {
        return $row->created_at->format('m');
    })
    ->map(function ($day) {

       // dd($day);
        return $day->sum('q1a');
    });
    }
```

However I only get white blank page at my blade file.

My blade file(count.blade.php) is like this

```
<h3>{{ $q1a }}</h3>
```

Could you teach me correct code please?
[image]

And one thing When I try to sum I got this error

> > Warning: A non-numeric value encountered

some of column are not number so I would like to adjust
fix controller code.

WEB.php

```
//calc total amount page
Route::get('count', 'ContactsController@count');
```

[UPDATE]
I wrote below code using Dear OMR's answer

```
   public function count()
        {
    Contact::whereYear('created_at', 2021)
            ->orderBy('created_at')
            ->select(['id','sno','s_date', DB::raw("MonthName(created_at)as monthName"), DB::raw('sum(q1a)')])
            ->groupBy(['id','sno','s_date', 'monthName', 'q1a'])->get();           
        }
```

count.blade.php code is below

```
@foreach ($values as $value)
  {{ $value->sumQ }}
@endforeach
```

Here is current dd result
[image]

Comment: please tell us where you call count() and how you got $q1a variable.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I'm sorry I can't follow your question mean. My goal is I would like to get each total sum q1a q2b q3c ... value. and those result are displayed as every month  Sep Nov Dec ... etc.

Comment: Your provided information is not enough to figure out the problem. you should show us your controller file, the one that called the count() method, and the part that pass variable $q1a into blade file.

Comment: Thank you again. I'm afraid to say My controller code is that it.
I update my web.php code and some of my info.

I think I made you confuse because of bad contorller code. 
Could you take a loot my dd iamge? I could stored values at my talbe. 
My next step is display each columns total amount.
I would like to display for example Feb result are  'q1a' is 4  'q1b' is 14 'q1c' is 5 ... 
"March" result are  'q1a' is 14  'q1b' is 9 'q1c' is 25 ...  April result are ....
etc I'm very sorry I've been make you confuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in DB stage, witch would be faster:

```
 $values=  Contact::whereYear('created_at', 2021)
                ->orderBy('created_at')
                ->select(['id','sno','s_date', DB::raw("MonthName(created_at)as monthName"), DB::raw('sum(q1a) as sumQ ')])
                ->groupBy(['id','sno','s_date', 'monthName'])->get();
```

**note**: any column you add it to select statement, should be also added in group by statement.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I'm trying your code and I have two question?  What is 'attempts'  I don't have this column and.  Could you teach me how to write {{ }} code at count.blade file ?

Comment: my bad!, it's not attempts but q1a, I use this column to test my code on my local db

Comment: you could make for each in your blade file and use $value->sumQ  as any other field

Comment: Thank you Dear OMR , Sorry I forgot foreach sentence. I update current code. I update dd result image too. I can get sumQ value but I can't display. Could you look at what is wrong please?

Comment: you should remove  'q1a' from group by clause

Comment: and adjust statement : DB::raw('sum(q1a) as sumQ ')

Comment: you result looks fine ... where is the problem?

Comment: Dear OMR thank you again. I see my result values are fine so My blade foreach code is wrong? I post my current blade file code. Is this okay?

Comment: I think the problem in sending data to your view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230243/discussion-between-omr-and-bluetail).